# Trying to figure out a modular respawn system

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I have two scripts, one for a `BoxCollider2D` Trigger for killing and respawning the player and another for setting a respawn point. When you touch the respawn point, it works perfectly, but when you then touch the kill collider, it returns an error after running through the duration of the respawn pause stating that `respawnPoint` is null.

For context, when I say modular respawn system, I mean a system where `respawnPoint` is the position of the latest one you've hit rather than one singular point.

I tried everything I could think of but I just can't figure it out. Anyone know what's wrong? (And maybe have some suggestions for how I could make the player disappear during the respawn window and reappear when respawned)

**Here are the scripts:**

*Respawn Point:*

```
public GameObject player;
public Vector2 respawnPoint;

private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
    if (other.CompareTag("Player"))
    {
        respawnPoint = player.transform.position;
        Debug.Log("Respawn Point Set");
    }

   
}
```

*KillingZone:*

```
public GameObject player;


private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
    if (other.CompareTag("Player"))
    {
        StartCoroutine(Respawn());
    }

    IEnumerator Respawn()
    {
        Debug.Log("Entered Killing");
        //Destroy Player
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1.5f);
        Debug.Log("Respawn");
        player.transform.position = gameObject.GetComponent<RespawnPoint>().respawnPoint;
    }

}
```

Comment: Without further knowledge I would guess that on your `KillingZone` here isn't a `RespawnPoint` component attached to the same `GameObject` ...